# Not able to run android apk file on emulator/device using calabash android setup

Tags: android, calabash

I am attempting calabash-android run file.apk.

I get the following output error msg

> Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password
>   was incorrect. (RuntimeError)

I also tried running this command

```
calabash-android resign file.apk
```

then also receiving same error. 
I have also set proper path of android-home and java-home in the environment variable and have added to the path

Any assistance in solving the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check: [Calabash-android sign issue](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/300) issue is already closed over GitHub.

Comment: user2886068 I'm facing the same issue as well. Please let me know as to how did you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios where I have encountered this to happen:

1. I found out that if the .android folder in your home directory might not have the file debug_keystore. If it does not have this file, go to your .android directory through terminal and then type out:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```
2. If you have extracted the test folder from a repository and the original uploader used a different gem version to generate the project structure, then you could see this. Solution would be to simply generate a new project structure and then include the tests in your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would ever do this but let's say you have a friend. And let's say this friend tried to troubleshoot without a clear direction and ran:

```
$ calabash-android setup
```

And imagine this friend took some crazy liberties with filling out the prompts and didn't realize his failed troubleshooting left a calabash_settings file in the root of his project directory. If he were to remove this file and follow Sunil's advice, everything might turn out okay for him.